# PHP stream short part of file from the middle

Tags: php, file-io, stream, output, fopen

Is there a way in PHP to output specific part in the middle of extremely large file without loading all the stuff into memory?
For example, to stream out 4.5MB from position 122,343,332.

Comment: read the file a line/block at a time, ignoring everything until you get the the position you want, then output what you need

Comment: do you mean showing particular string from a particular file ? like what `substr()` does ?

Comment: Like streaming out image from a file which contains thousands of them